# UIView or UIViewController subclass?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller, calayer

I'm trying to refactor my code in the best possible way and I'm wondering what the proper architecture for the given situation is.

**What I'm Trying To Do**

What I'm doing is pretty simple: I have some custom `CALayer` subclasses that represent an interactive UI element. They are broken up into multiple layers since some of the parts of the UI are static, so I didn't want to redraw those static elements needlessly. Right now, the layers are added as sublayers in the initialization part of a `CustomView` class that is a subclass of `UIView`.

There is currently **no** corresponding `CustomViewController` class that is a subclass of `UIViewController` because when I'm using the `CustomView`, it's contained within a `UITableViewCell` or a part of a generic `UIViewController` with other views in it, so I felt another `UIViewController` for each `CustomView` instance would be redundant.

Also of importance is the that the only operation that I'm doing inside of the `UIView` class is I'm responding to touch events and sending the touch information to the sublayers so that the UI can update its appearance accordingly. I'm not overriding the `drawRect` method or anything like that.

**The Question**

Basically, I'm trying to figure out whether I should either:

*Option 1:*

Get rid of the `CustomView` class, create a `CustomViewController` class that is a subclass of `UIViewController`, and simply add the `CALayer` objects as sublayers of the `CustomViewController`'s built-in `view` property.

or

*Option 2:*

My thinking about the `UIViewController` subclass being redundant is correct, so I should leave it the way I have it and have a `CustomView` class with the `CALayer` objects inside of it.

I would highly appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: I've done this exactly the same as you have in the past. I've also done it with a UIViewController. As long as the code is maintainable and performant then I guess it doesn't really matter. The UIViewController is (I guess) the more "correct" way of doing this but it might also hinder performance especially if you're putting it inside a UITableViewCell and there could be many of them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Good to hear I'm not way off in the non-`UIViewController` way that it's implemented currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in terms of MVC, the code you're describing (option #2) is well written and maintains a very clear boundary of responsibility. You're not writing any code that has nothing to do with the view layer itself in this class which is great. I think that in this case there's no need for a separate `UIViewController` subclass to manage these instances because as you said - they are handling their own touch events and visible layers (exactly their responsibility).

If for any reason there is a need for something more complex that requires data related logic or other such computation, I would definitely consider subclassing a `UIViewController` or maybe looking at the problem in an entirely different way.

Given the situation you've presented, I think that maintaining the `CALayer` instance within this `UIView` subclass ('CustomView') is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Although it's not implemented yet, the UI element will be animating based on information that gets saved/loaded from iCloud. Do you think that since I'll be using iCloud I should implement the `UIViewController` method described in option 1? An alternative to option 1 would be to do something like `CustomView *cv = [[CustomView alloc] initWithData: elementData];`, where elementData has already been loaded by the `UITableViewController`, etc. However, that alternative probably breaks the MVC concept since its intermingling the view with the model.

Comment: In my opinion, a subclass of UIView should not have an 'initWithData' method - this is with no doubt a contradiction to the MVC paradigm. If data is to be downloaded from iCloud, there could be place to consider something more complex. On the other hand, I see a lot of UIImageView subclasses that handle cache for instance - cache has to do with storage (not in any way related to view elements). There is definite "right" and "wrong" in this matter, though it's important to maintain understandable code.

Comment: After I posted that, I thought that instead of giving the UI element the actual data, I could just have a method that sets an arbitrary integer that the element should animate to. For example, when setting up the `UITableViewCell`, I could do the following: `[[CustomView alloc] initWithValue: data.integerValue];`where data is the iCloud data that has been loaded by the `UITableViewController` and `integerProperty` is the value that directly corresponds to the appearance of the UI element. I think that would preserve the integrity of the MVC paradigm.

Comment: True, sounds like a fair pattern